Converting pdf to images gives squares in text areas of the converted image
I'm trying to convert pdf to image using the following code, but the conversion is working fine but for each element in the pdf it gives a square over the element like for each text area there is a square
from io import BytesIO
import PyPDF2
from pdf2image import convert_from_bytes

# Assuming "file" is an InMemoryUploadedFile object containing the PDF content
# Read the PDF content from the InMemoryUploadedFile
pdf_content = file.read()

# Create a BytesIO object to handle the PDF content
pdf_stream = BytesIO(pdf_content)

# Use PyPDF2 to get the number of pages in the PDF (optional step)
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_stream)
num_pages = pdf_reader.numPages

# Convert the PDF content to images using pdf2image
images = convert_from_bytes(pdf_content, poppler_path=r"C:\Python\poppler\poppler-23.07.0\Library\bin")

# Save each image
for i, pdf in enumerate(images):
    # Save pages as images in the pdf
    pdf.save(f'PDF\image_mods\image_converted_{i + 1}.png', 'PNG'

)

In order to debug your image conversion issue you simply need to bypass any problems introduced by wrapping the core programming invocation.
Since you are using Windows variant which should currently be 24.07 I will use that in description but you will need to edit to your current version.
In a text file paste this debugging command
PDF2PNG.cmd
if not exist c:\test\ md c:\test
"C:\Python\poppler\poppler-24.07.0\Library\bin\pdftoppm.exe" -progress -png -r 150 "%~1" "c:\test\%~n1-Page"

Now rename that file to PDF2PNG.cmd and drop your test file on it or use it as a shell command like
pdf2png.cmd input.pdf
If you have a file with pages you will see the count is known and will output files per page such as here will be 1-77,
1 77 c:\temp\input-Page-01.png
2 77 c:\test\input-Page-02.png
3 77 c:\test\input-Page-03.png
4 77 c:\test\input-Page-04.png
5 77 c:\test\input-Page-05.png
6 77 c:\test\input-Page-06.png
7 77 c:\test\input-Page-07.png
8 77 c:\test\input-Page-08.png
9 77 c:\test\input-Page-09.png
10 77 c:\test\input-Page-10.png
...
77 77 c:\test\input-Page-77.png

If you find the results are better than your current usage. Then use that one line command format string in your python. To replace all those other ones. If you want higher quality use -r 200 etc. (There are many other options in the manual)
